# Why is my strcpy() not overwriting the whole string and keeping characters from the last char []?

Tags: c, overwrite, strcpy

I have a simple method that takes in a file name and a pointer to a linked list. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the linkedlist. However, I noticed that for some reason, strcpy seems to be failing to overwrite the string that used to be there. With each time that I overwrite the char array, the copy gets worse and worse. **Why is strcpy holding on to previous data?**

```
void readFile(struct record ** recordArray, char inputArray [])
{

struct record ** temp = recordArray;
char theString [100];
char characterInput;
int counter = 0;
counter  = 0;
FILE * infile = fopen(inputArray, "r");

char name [100];
char address [100];
int yearofbirth;
char telno [20];

int target = 0;
/*
0 name
1 address
2 yearofbirth
3 telno
*/

/*If the file exists*/
if (infile != NULL)
{ 
   while (characterInput != EOF)
   {
        characterInput = fgetc(infile);

        if (characterInput == '\n')
        {
            theString[counter] = '\0';

            if (target == 0)/*name*/
            {
                strcpy(name, theString);
                counter = 0;
                target++;
            }
            else if (target == 1) /*address*/
            {
                strcpy(address, theString);
                counter = 0;
                target++;
            }
            else if (target == 2) /*yearofbirth*/
            {
                yearofbirth = atoi(theString);
                counter = 0;
                target++;
            }
            else if (target == 3) /*telephone number*/
            {
                strcpy(telno, theString);
                counter = 0;
                target = 0;
                addRecord(temp, name, address, yearofbirth, telno);
            }
        }
        else /*if the character is not a null line ie its a regular character*/
        {
          theString[counter] = characterInput;  
          counter++;   
        }
   } 
}
else
{
    printf("Error: There has to be a file named: %s\n", inputArray);
}
fclose(infile);
```

}

**INPUT:**

```
bill
firstaddress
9119398644
1993

tim
birch st.
7567115
1980

roger
wood st drive
4830382
1909
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Name: bill
Address: firstaddress
Birthyear: 529464052
Telephone Number: 1993398644ss

Name: tim3398644ss
Address: birch st.4ss
Birthyear: 7567115
Telephone Number: 1980115t.4ss

Name: timmy15t.4ss
Address: wood st drive
Birthyear: 4830382
Telephone Number: 1909382 drive
```

**EDIT:**

This is the code that ended up working. Thank you folks.

```
void readFile(struct record ** recordArray, char inputArray [])
{

struct record ** temp = recordArray;
char theString [100];
char characterInput;
int counter = 0;
counter  = 0;
FILE * infile = fopen(inputArray, "r");

char name [100];
char address [100];
int yearofbirth;
char telno [20];

int target = 0;
/*
0 name
1 address
2 yearofbirth
3 telno
*/

/*If the file exists*/
if (infile != NULL)
{ 
   while (characterInput != EOF)
   {
        characterInput = fgetc(infile);

        if (characterInput == '\n')
        {
            theString[counter] = '\0';

            if (target == 0)/*name*/
            {
                strcpy(name, theString);
                counter = 0;
                target++;
            }
            else if (target == 1) /*address*/
            {
                strcpy(address, theString);
                counter = 0;
                target++;
            }
            else if (target == 2) /*yearofbirth*/
            {
                yearofbirth = atoi(theString);
                counter = 0;
                target++;
            }
            else if (target == 3) /*telephone number*/
            {
                strcpy(telno, theString);
                counter = 0;
                target = 0;
                addRecord(temp, name, address, yearofbirth, telno);
            }
        }
        else /*if the character is not a null line ie its a regular character*/
        {
          theString[counter] = characterInput;  
          counter++;   
        }
   } 
}
else
{
    printf("Error: There has to be a file named: %s\n", inputArray);
}
fclose(infile);
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: (1) You don't terminate `theString` with a null character ´'\0'` when you read a new-line character. (2) You don't guard `theString` against overflow when appending data.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I think you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to terminate the input string with a `'\0'`.

Change:

```
    if (characterInput == '\n')
    {
        if (target == 0)/*name*/
        {
            ...
```

to:

```
    if (characterInput == '\n')
    {
        theString[counter] = '\0';  // terminate input string

        if (target == 0)/*name*/
        {
            ...
```

Comment: That worked great thank you! I thought I had tried that before but I suppose not. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
void readFile(struct record ** recordArray, char inputArray []){

    struct record ** temp = recordArray;
    char theString [100];
    char characterInput;
    int counter = 0;
    counter  = 0;
    FILE * infile = fopen(inputArray, "r");

    char name [100];
    char address [100];
    char yearofbirth[100];
    char telno [100];

    char *buff=name; // initially is the name
    int target = 0;
    /*
    0 name
    1 address
    2 yearofbirth
    3 telno
    */



    if (!infile)
    {
        printf("Error: There has to be a file named: %s\n", inputArray);
        return;
    }
    char lastChar=0;
   while (characterInput != EOF)
   {
        characterInput = fgetc(infile);


        if (characterInput == '\n')
        {
            if(lastChar==characterInput)
                continue; /*empty line*/

            target++;
            target%=4;
            *buff=0; // null terminate the string
            switch(target){
                case   0:/*name*/
                    addRecord(temp, name, address, atoi( yearofbirth), telno);
                    buff=name;
                    break;
               case 1: /*address*/
                    buff=address;
                    break;
               case 2: /*yearofbirth*/
                    buff=yearofbirth;
                    break;
               case 3: /*telephone number*/
                    buff=telno;

                }
        }
        else /*if the character is not a null line ie its a regular character*/
        {
          *buff = characterInput;  
          buff++;   
        }
        lastChar=characterInput;
   } 


    fclose(infile);

    if(buff!=name) // last record?
        addRecord(temp, name, address,atoi( yearofbirth), telno);
}
```